# how to resolve ts type of params in namespace with vue3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

tq.d.ts

```
// import type {defineComponent} from "vue";    // it doesn't work! how to resolve it ?
declare namespace TQ
{
    declare class TQPanel
    {
        constructor(params: defineComponent);   // params type shoud be  defineComponent
    }
}
```

test.ts

```
new TQ.TQPanel({
    data(){
        return{
          msg:'abc'
        }
    },
    methods:{
        test(){
            console.log(this.msg);  // TS2339: Property 'msg' does not exist on type '{ test(): void; }'.
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.msg);
    }
})
```

i try to import defineComponent in x.d.ts ,but it will get new error : 'cannot find name TQ'